# How much does the top 21 producers make per a day?

Tags: block-producer

Does the top 21 EOS producers make a different amount per day or a set amount?

Comment: different amount based on how many blocks they produced and how many votes they have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @confused00 said it depends, if you want to take a look at the actual numbers, here you are.

https://eosauthority.com/producers_rank

Answer (score 1):

As of October 24, 2018 below is the daily reward for block producers:

Average 100-800 eos a day.

[image]